# OMS Alert email shows a max of 10 records in the email body and the link/query to complete result set on the portal

Tags: azure, azure-alerts, azure-oms, oms

OMS Alert email shows a max of 10 records in the email body and the link to complete result set to visualize on the portal. How do we increase the number of records being shown/sent in email, if possible.

Answer (score 0):

The expected feature is currently not supported. If interested, I recommend to raise feedback [here](https://feedback.azure.com/forums/602299-azure-monitor-alert-management) in UserVoice / feedback forum. [Here](https://feedback.azure.com/forums/602299-azure-monitor-alert-management/suggestions/30932506-customize-alert-email) is the most related one that I could find and [here](https://feedback.azure.com/forums/602299-azure-monitor-alert-management?query=alert%20email) are few other related feature requests that are already raised which you may upvote that are of interest. In general, Azure feature / product team would check feasibility of a feature request, prioritize against existing feature backlog, add them in roadmap as appropriate and would announce and/or update the related Azure document once a feature request is addressed.